# Unable to use any Root path in Intellij only Absolute path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path, absolute-path

I am having trouble with IntelliJ recognizing file paths when the file is located outside of the src folder. This problem only occurs when the file path is not an absolute path, and it is causing me issues as I need to manually change all file paths. My project structure is as follows:

- ProjectName

  - .idea
  - db
  - src

    - controllers dir
    - routers dir
    - database dir
    - index.js

For example, I cannot access the db folder from the src/database directory. I am experiencing this issue across multiple projects with assets located outside the src folder. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have also tried ../ and / in front with no success.

[File Setup][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXB5G.png

db = new Database('db/data.sqlite'); is the code I am trying.

Edit: I opened in VS Code and it runs with no issues so I assume its an issue with intellij, going to contact jetBrains for a solution. Will update when it is fixed.

Comment: It _should_ be, _"db/filename"_.  You're saying this doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work, unless it is the absolute path

Comment: What have you configured as "working directory" in your run config? Everything is relative to that directory.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that if you want to access some resource from the classpath, it needs to be in the directory configured as the resource root, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html,

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct but in the terminal I'm at the start of the folder, ProjectName.

Comment: Do you use the terminal to start your program?

Comment: No, i just use the run button in intellij

Comment: You'll need to locate what your working directory is, you can find it under _File > Project Structure > Modules > your module > Sources_.  The top directory, there, is the working directory.  Alternately, you can print out an empty _File_ object to the standard-out, and see what the path it, _new File("")_.

Comment: The working directory is the ProjectName. When I try the new File method it shows the current path to the file I'm running.

Comment: C:\Users\5600X\Desktop\MTBHub_backend\src\database         This is my working directory when I run, however when I run it in VSC, it ends at MTBHub_backend. And when I follow what Reilas said, the WD is the ProjectName. Maybe an issue with the Run Config?